# Euler list output in steps (Animation nodes)

Tags: animation-nodes

I try to create an euler list that adds a rotation every so many times. In this case adding 72 degrees every 3 times.

I would be thankful if someone could help me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `Float Range` and `Repeat List Element` node you can do this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your anwer Hari, yes indeed, but then repeating values every 3 times. So I want index 0,1,2 to have a value of 72. Index 3,4,5 to have a value of 144. Index 6,7,8 to have a value of 216 and so forth. Like the blue text indicates in the example image. Do you maybe know a way to do this? Again, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Vince I have updated answer

Comment: Yes exactly like that! I tried everything with a repeat list which was wrong apparently. Thanks for your answer, it helps me a lot!

Comment: there is repeat list and repeat list element node, may be be you confused by those two :)